# where can I find the silverlight 4.0 for the production server?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, production-environment

where can I find the silverlight 4.0 for the production server ?

For this need to install vs 2010 ?

or only need to install 4.0 from where can I find the 4.0 for the production server ?

is there any license for the same or its free ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really any concept of setting up a "Production" server for Silverlight itself.  You would normally just configure the object tag in the html like this:-

```
     <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/YourApp.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50303.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50303.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object>
```

This will allow any clients that don't yet have the RTM Silverlight 4 plugin to download and install from Microsoft.

If you are talking about the server-side components needed to support a silverlight app that you may have built with VS2010 well thats a very very good question.

If you were to create a Silverlight 4 Business application from the standard template in VS2010 you will end up with a web app targeting .NET 4.  So that application will require that the server to support ASP.NET with .NET 4 on the server.

I'm sure its quite possible to develop a Silverlight 4 application that uses 3.5 on the server-side.  However its likely that developer experience in VS2010 is going to be hard core since I suspect many of the conveniences created to make developing such apps speedy will not work.  Of course this only a suspicion, I'll try to give it a go sometime to see what the realy experience is.

Answer (score 0):

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156

or for more info:

http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/

Answer (score 0):

As Anthony stated there isn't really much required on the server itself host Silverlight. It's a client technology so 99% of the work is done by the client plugin and the html in Anthony's answer.

However you do need to setup the mime types for Silverlight on the server which you can read up on at [Configuring IIS for Silverlight Applications](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/262/configuring-iis-for-silverlight-applications/)